# Location Service in Background - Android Native

Tags: android, mobile-application, location-services

I need to Post my current location from my Android app at regular intervals (say every 5 min), while my app is in the background.

What is the component that i should use to implement the above ..in Android Native ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Service` to send your information to your server. Presumably, you've got that under control.

Your `Service` should be started by an alarm triggered by the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), where you can specify an interval. Unless you have to report your data exactly every 5 minutes, you probably want the inexact alarm so you can save some battery life.

Finally, you can register your app to get the bootup broadcast by setting up a BroadcastReceiver like so:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            // Register your reporting alarms here.            
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the following permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` for that to work. Don't forget to register your alarms when you run the app normally, or they'll only be registered when the device boots up.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```